# v-select sorts by "item-text"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a [v-select](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/) that I made using Vuetify. How can I sort from largest to smallest for the names of the items in this v-select?

```
<v-select
  v-model="selectedFruits"
  :items="fruits"
  label="Favorite Fruits"
  item-text="text"
  return-object
  multiple
>


    fruits: [ { text: 'x', id: '1'}, 
    { text: 'y', id: '2'}, 
    { text: 'a', id: '5'},
    { text: 'h', id: '4'}],
```

I used the sort method but failed.

Comment: Depends how you do sort `fruits`. What is not working exactly?

Comment: fruits do not come to me in order sir

Comment: Add the code snippet of `fruits`.

Comment: largest/smallest in term of what?

Comment: I added fruits sir

Comment: I want to sort by initials

Comment: Can you provide an example of how is `fruits` going to look like?

Comment: ```const sortedFruits = fruits.sort()```

should work

Comment: Do you mind sharing what you have initially and what you want to have at the end?

Comment: listed in order x-y-a-h. I want a-h-x-y

Answer (score 0):

This should work well

```html
<template>
  <pre>{{ alphaSortedFruits }}</pre>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fruits: [
        { text: 'x', id: '1' },
        { text: 'y', id: '2' },
        { text: 'a', id: '5' },
        { text: 'h', id: '4' },
      ],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    alphaSortedFruits() {
      return this.fruits.slice().sort((a, b) => a.text.localeCompare(b.text))
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Here is [a playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp1Us1OwzAMfhUrl7VSlwoEl6pMQki8AEfCIWs9mqk/UeLCUNV3x+naMontknx2Ptuf7Qzi2Vr51aPIRE7Y2FoT7lQLkFuHu2EAXdtKv3WOsHx1vSEP45in4VG1eXoRwqYvnLHEGE+WI6DEg+5rgiEkLDXpKD5jAIfUu3axAA5T7gzeFwfAAIQnymBz2iRgSgZ3GxiTK4SfhXB/g6AXwuMNQrUQHi4JHzMaw3V2F11je55Ftkj/N5+/HtcuqTJenjuUvjYFRrH0HBJFOoF9DE870DIokXVX6BpfuIh2GO0nZxzPKiYB4WQ9eboOWyTCNGHe20ZbefRdy8ucJKj5wSux6lWCtx1sJSoi67M09YcifIGjl537TBlJ17dkGpTom+3edd8eHSdWYhLA9cX4C5bQsnk=).

The actual result

[image]

---

Few notes:

- uou are not obliged to use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#sorting_non-ascii_characters), you can also use a "regular sort"
- I'm using `slice()` to have a copy of the array too, I assumed that you didn't want to mutate the original one
- keep in mind that `slice` is doing a shallow copy, if you do have a deeply nested object you'll need to use [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone). Great thing is that it's quite performant and also native, no need for lodash anymore.